# Using Symbolic Links to publish Assets in Yii2 without file copying?

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

Not all servers allow AssetManager to publish assets by creating new directories at runtime, e.g. Google AppEngine.

Yii2 Docs talk about using Symbolic Links to publish asset files, i.e. without actually copying asset files in a new location. [Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$linkAssets-detail)

Is Symbolic Links an answer to this problem?
Can someone give me a basic example of how to use Symbolic Links in Yii2 when deployed on a shared server?

**EDIT**

As [docs on a popular shared server godaddy](https://in.godaddy.com/help/creating-symbolic-links-with-linux-hosting-accounts-8375) suggest, do I need to follow such manual procedure for every file I want to publish? Is there any way to do the same on Google AppEngine?

Comment: It's just a config option in Yii, The Docs you linked explain it. You'd need to check what your hosting supports.

Comment: I've added godaddy docs. please take a moment to have a look at it. can you write an example of using symbolic links. atleast a simplest example.